# Is there any way to get the HTML from a web page once the JavaScript is loaded in a Flutter app?

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-html

I'm working on a URL preview widget, so I'd like to extract the meta tags from the HTML of a given URL.

However, the problem is that websites like Twitter don't return the entire HTML when they detect there's no JavaScript engine enabled (i.e. doing a GET request from the http package).

So, I'd like to know if there's any workaround for these cases, for example, using some kind of headless browser to get the entire HTML.

Thanks!

Comment: I doubt that twitter returns different `meta` HTML tags depending on the browser. Can you please give a specific example what you are trying to achieve? e.g. including the URLs you request, what you get and what you want to extract.

Comment: In order to get an specific example, you can simply follow the following steps:

1. Take the URL of a random tweet (e.g. last tweet posted by the official account: https://twitter.com/Twitter/status/1288789234984222724).

2. Open the dev tools (and search for the "og:title" element, for example).

3. Disable JavaScript.

4. Reload the page and look again for the "og:title" element. You'll notice it has disappeared.

Anyway, I'd like to solve this kind of issue also for other edge cases (i.e. parsing the HTML once JS has been loaded).

Thanks @herbert!! :)

Comment: as you have just proven, Twitter returns the same HTML, no matter if javascript is enabled or not. it's just that javascript inserts those tags after the fact once it executes.

So I guess your question is if you can execute javascript? I guess you could try `webview_flutter` But i don't think this is really feasible. I think a better approach is to use a webservice to render a preview. There are quite a few thumbnail services out there (e.g.https://thumbnail.ws/) or you could use chrome in headless mode yourself.

Comment: did you find any solution to this ?